# Add non-osgi jars to RCP4 project

Tags: osgi, rcp

I am building an RCP4 application.

I have two non-osgi jars called a.jar and b.jar.  Both jars have tons of non-osgi dependencies. One of the dependencies of a.jar is b.jar.  So the hierarchy looks like this:

```
My application
|--a.jar
|----aDependency1.jar
|----aDependency2.jar
|----aDependencyN.jar
|----b.jar
|------bDependency1.jar
|------bDependency2.jar
|------bDependencyN.jar
```

Some of the bDependencyN.jars are different versions of the aDependencyN.jars
(An example is commons-logging-1.0.4.jar vs commons-logging-1.1.2.jar)

I need to directly reference a.jar and b.jar from my RCP4 application. In other words, when I write code, I will import packages from a.jar and b.jar)

Which is the best approach:

- Use bnd 2.4 via command-line to turn all non-osgi jars into osgi ones.  I then add every jar to my project via target file
- Create a new project "Plug-in from existing JAR archives", and select a.jar and all of its dependencies and export it as a "deployable plugin and fragment" called a.with.libs.jar. I do the same with b.jar and create b.with.libs.jar.  I then add those 2 new jars to my project via target file
- Create a new project "Plug-in from existing JAR archives", and select a.jar and all of its dependencies, and b.jar and all of its dependencies and export it as a "deployable plugin and fragment" called ab.with.libs.jar. I then add the new jar to my project via target file
- Is there a better approach than the suggestions above?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [bnd-platform](https://github.com/stempler/bnd-platform) (I am also the author) to manage third party dependencies and create OSGi bundles from them. You can use it with both dependencies retrieved from Maven repositories and local Jars (see the [README](https://github.com/stempler/bnd-platform#local-dependencies)). When you configure a Maven dependency it will also include the transitive dependencies. Under the hood it uses bnd. If needed you can also customize how the Jars are wrapped. *bnd-platform* is a plugin for Gradle, you can easily start with [this template](https://github.com/stempler/bnd-platform-minimal) - just add your dependencies and provide the configuration as described in the project README (bundle symbolic names, versions) and run `gradlew bundles`. The created bundles can then be added to the target platform. You can also use *bnd-platform* to build a p2 repository / update site.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding.  My current project does not use Maven and I have never used Gradle before.  The documentation on the bnd-platform website seems a little advanced for me and I would not know where to begin to setup a correct gradle file that mirrors the example above (all local jars).

Comment: If it's all local Jars (and not Maven dependencies) bnd-platform loses a bit of its benefit as it can't add transitive dependencies automatically. As starting point you can use the template I mentioned above, from the documentation you only need the local dependencies section to add the Jars: https://github.com/stempler/bnd-platform#local-dependencies